# Redis насколько верна такая реализация меню?

Tags: redis, nosql

Сейчас храню меню в Redis, каждый пункт меню представляет из себя отдельную запись. Каждый пункт меню связан со своим родителем (1 к 1) и дочерними меню (1 ко многим).

Создание пунктов в меню выглядит следующим образом:

1. Создаю пункты меню:

   HMSET menu_item:1 menu_title Главное меню

   HMSET menu_item:2 menu_title Мой профиль

   HMSET menu_item:3 menu_title Моя статистика
2. Указываю каждому меню, кто его "родитель" (он всегда 1)

   SADD menu_item:1:parent 0

   SADD menu_item:2:parent 1

   SADD menu_item:3:parent 2
3. Указываю пунктам меню, кто его "дети", если такие есть (их может быть несколько)

   SADD menu_item:1:childs 2

   SADD menu_item:2:childs 3

**Проблема с которой я столкнулся пользуясь такой структурой:**

Когда я хочу отобразить пользователю меню, то мне нужно получить все пункты меню у которых родитель == номеру текущего пункта меню пользователя.
Для этого я я получаю "детей" текущего меню с помощью `SMEMBERS menu_item:1:childs`, который возвращает например `{'4','2','6'}` и после я вынужден создавать pipeline и внутри, в цикле брать каждого из этих детей по очереди с помощью `HGETALL`, после чего еще и сортировать силами языка программирования python получившийся массив (у каждого пункта меню свой порядок).

**Вопрос**
Правильно ли я вообще реализовал меню и есть ли способ сделать это лучше, например как-то избежав цикла в pipeline, где приходиться выбирать каждый элемент по очереди? По факту, мне нужно часто выполнять следующий запрос к хранилищу (приведу пример на SQL)

Как бы я получал детей определенного пункта меню в SQL бд:

```
1) SELECT * FROM `menu_items` WHERE `parent_id` = 1 ORDER BY `position` ASC
```

Comment: У вас часто меняется информация по пунктам меню ? Если нет, я бы сериалазовал в какой нибудь json все пункты входящие в один раздел. причем положил бы их в виде массива в нужном порядке и в каждом элементе собственно и хранил всю информацию относящуюся к пункту, включая наименование и id данного элемента (по этому id можно будет получить полное его содержимое). По крайней мере получение будет мгновенным

Comment: С получением 1 элемента нет проблем, но когда я хочу получить все пункты меню с определенным критерием (например родитель должен быть == иду 1), то мне приходиться много раз вызывать команду HGETALL к каждому элементу
Разве ваше предложение решит эту проблему??? Все равно ведь придется это делать

Comment: так если этот критерий именно "родитель", то как раз по ключу с id родителя лежит одна единственная запись, которая полностью описывает все элементы, которые в нем содержаться, вместе с названиями и прочими полями

Comment: https://pastebin.com/T42Sr9vD

Comment: По хорошему в элементе кроме собственно описания пунктов которые в нем находятся можно положить еще id родителя, что бы можно было быстро найти этого самого родителя, что бы поправить наименование самого пункта

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, ваш вариант идеально подошёл, вынесете текст комментария в ответ и я выберу его правильным)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю сериализовать все пункты одного раздела меню в один ключ redis в виде json или чего то подобного. Сам ключ содержит id раздела меню, который описывает. Описание каждого пункта меню в массиве содержит его id и наименование, что позволяет сразу выводить все разделы, не обращаясь за наименованиями в другие ключи redis. В описании элемента меню, помимо входящих в него пунктов стоит добавить id родительского элемента, это упростит задачу редактирования наименования самого элемента, поскольку оно описано в родителе. Пример хранения вышеописанным способом:

```
key menu_item-0 => { menu: [
  { name: "Меню1", id: 2 },
  { name: "Меню2", id: 3 }
]}

key menu_item-2 => { parent: 0, menu: [
  { name: "Элемент 1-1 (субменю)", id: 4 },
  { name: "Элемент 1-2", id: 5}
]}

key menu_item-3 => { parent: 0, menu: [ .... ]}

key menu_item-4 => { parent: 2, menu: [
  { name: "Элемент 1-1-1", id: 10 },
  { name: "Элемент 1-1-2", id: 11}
]}
```